# getting data from nested Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been trying to extract data from a multi level dictionary in python 
example of dictionary i am extracting from is:

```
{"family": {
"name": "Mary",
"age": "32",
"sex": "female",
"kids": [
  {
    "name": "jim",
    "age": "10",
    "sex": "male",
    "dob_year": "2007",
    "ssn": "123-23-1234"
  },
  {
    "name": "jill",
    "age": "6",
    "sex": "female",
    "dob_year": "2011",
    "ssn": "123-23-1235"
  }]}}


ss = test0["family"]["kids"]

def search(values, lookup):
    for k in values:
        for v in values:
            if lookup in v:
                return k
    return None
print search(ss, '201')
```

my goal is for it to search keywords (not exact) in the values of the nested dictionary and return either the full dictionary or a value of a particular key like "23-23-1235" if ssn is asked for.

need it to return {"name": "jill","age": "6","sex": "female","dob_year": "2011","ssn": "123-23-1235"} of a request value in the different levels.

Right now it only shows:{"name": "jim","age": "10","sex": "male",
"dob_year": "2007","ssn": "123-23-1234"}

Comment: Check on your loop logic, and you should use `dict.iteritems()` to read items in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
test0 = {"family": {
"name": "Mary",
"age": "32",
"sex": "female",
"kids": [
  {
    "name": "jim",
    "age": "10",
    "sex": "male",
    "dob_year": "2007",
    "ssn": "123-23-1234"
  },
  {
    "name": "jill",
    "age": "6",
    "sex": "female",
    "dob_year": "2011",
    "ssn": "123-23-1235"
  }]}}


ss = test0["family"]["kids"]
def search(values, lookup):
    for k in values:
        if any(lookup in str(s) for s in k.values()):
            return k
    return None
print search(ss, '201')
```

it will print out:

```
{'age': '6', 'dob_year': '2011', 'name': 'jill', 'ssn': '123-23-1235', 'sex': 'female'}
```

Comment: that work for that particular dictionary but if i switch dictionaries i get "argument of type 'int' is not iterable" it is in the same format just different keys and values

Comment: @KAM_00 I think there is integer number in the dict values, you can convert to string with function `str()`.

Answer (score 0):

> What if it matches two results ?

if it matches more than one result but still it will return only one return because function return one at a time by memory so the solution is store result somewhere like use a list to store the result and then return it at last , first let see if it match two results then what the issue :

Simple solution

```
 def search(values, lookup):
        for item in values:
            for key,value in item.items():
                if lookup in value:
                    return item
        return None
    print(search(ss, '20'))
```

it matches two results but the output is :

```
{'dob_year': '2007', 'ssn': '123-23-1234', 'sex': 'male', 'age': '10', 'name': 'jim'}
```

so the solution is:

```
def search(values, lookup):
    result = []

    for item in values:
        for key,value in item.items():
            if lookup in value:
                if item not in result:
                    result.append(item)

    if result:
        return result
    else:
        return None
print(search(ss, '20'))
```

output:

```
[{'ssn': '123-23-1234', 'sex': 'male', 'dob_year': '2007', 'age': '10', 'name': 'jim'}, {'ssn': '123-23-1235', 'sex': 'female', 'dob_year': '2011', 'age': '6', 'name': 'jill'}]
```